# Sitecore The layout for the requested document was not found

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1

Getting below error while browsing CD site (Web DB) in sitecore.while browsing CMS site it's works fine.What could be the issue .We have restored the web db from master still facing same issue.

Error :

> The layout for the requested document was not found
>
> Most likely causes:
>   The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) may have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> What you can try:
>
> Go back to the previous page
>   Go to the start page
>
> Additional Information:
>
> Requested URL:   /mysite/res/book
>   Requested Layout:    {62A89386-861F-5210-9568-H8CADA118FFB}
>   Requested Device:    Default
>   If the page you are trying to display exists, please check that an appropriate prefix has been added to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

If the url works on your CM box and doesn't work on CD box, it looks like something is not published.

Try:

1. Login to your CM server and publish the whole site again with `Republish everything` option selected.
2. If 1. doesn't help, login to Sitecore Desktop, switch to the `web` database, navigate in Content Editor to the item you want to see. Check if the item is there and if presentation details are correct.
3. If item is NOT in `web` or layout is not in `web` database, switch back to `master` database and check if publishing restrictions are applied or if the item is in the final state of a workflow.
4. If the item and layouts are in the `web` database but the url still doesn't work, check your `sites` configuration in `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` whether your site is not restricted to some host names.

Comment: not related to user login and restriction etc. even not required to republish.I got the solution will post here soon.currently i am workig on it.

Comment: solution 1: point to different environment core DB (or restore core DB from different environment) and it's started working fine.

Comment: solution 2: restore web DB from master DB also worked for me.